# Simple_form submit button its not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im new on rails. Im trying to validate the input value in a simple_form. If the values correct then redirect to a external url.
But the submit button its not working.

My model:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :keyword, presence: true
  validates :keyword, inclusion: { in: %w(marketing pepe),

  message: "%{value} its not valid " }
end
```

My controller

```
  def new
    @course = Course.new
  end

  def create
    @course = Course.new(params[:keyword])

    if @course.keyword == "marketing"
      @course.save
      redirect_to ('https://res.cloudinary.com/...pdf')
    end
  end
```

my view

```
  <h2>Do you have a code?</h2>
  <%= simple_form_for @course do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :keyword, label: 'Your keyword please', placeholder: "puts here" %>
    <%= f.submit 'take it' %>
  <% end %>
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: you should describe more detail about your `expected` and the `actual` result, it could help to understand your situation.

Comment: When you say your Submit button is "not working", do you mean that you can't click on it in the browser, or that when you click it doesn't do anything, or that you can't work out what to do when it's clicked? One thing to try is to add the `byebug` gem to your project. You can then add the line `byebug` anywhere in your controller to see what the variables look like at that point - can be very useful to check that Rails is executing your code as you expect!